# Calculating the period, frequency, and confirming multimeter readings

Tags: frequency, oscilloscope, graph

I have some readings from an Oscilloscope that I want to take info from and calculate the period, frequency, and then confirm some multimeter readings I took.

For the 1st:
[image]

The function generator had these settings:

Vlow = -8V and Vhigh = 8V

125KHz square wave

Multimeter reading of 258.9mv AC

Next,

For the 2nd:
[image]

The function generator had these settings:

Vlow = 0V and Vhigh = 5V

300KHz square wave

Multimeter reading of 2.430V DC

To summarize, I want to calculate the period, frequency (Only using the pictures), and then confirm that the multimeter readings I took are correct.

The reason I ask these things is that I do not understand how to read these pictures correctly.

Thanks for any possible help.

Comment: Are you sure the first multimeter reading range is correct, or was it the same as the 2nd?

Comment: @SpehroPefhany I don't quite remember but the DC one was something like -0.048V or -0.0048V, if that is what you are asking.

Comment: Most multimeters can't work at frequencies as high as you are using.  The measured results are wrong, misleading, and inaccurate.

Comment: For the second picture, the meter reading of 2.43 VDC is reasonable.  The meter will show something close to the average value ov the waveform.  For a 0/5V square wave, that should be 2.50 volts.

Comment: Your first one is listed 258.9mv AC. Was it AC or DC?

Comment: @SpehroPefhany That was using the AC setting. If you refer to my above comment, doesn't something around zero make sense? Since it is from -8V to 8V DC?

Comment: The reading will be unreliable on AC on most cheap multimeters because of the high frequency. It would be plausible for DC. If you reduced the frequency to near mains frequency I would expect a reading close to 9VAC if not true RMS or 8VAC if RMS-reading.

Comment: Most likely the test freq is out of range for your meter, but watch out for crest factor on slower signals too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the  first picture, your oscilloscope was set for a horizontal scale of 2.00 microseconds per division and a vertical scale of 2 volts per division.  Since one period of your signal occupied 4 horizontal divisions, the period is 4X2 = 8 microseconds.  Taking the reciprocal of 8 microseconds yields a frequency of 125 kHz. The vertical extent of your signal is 8 divisions so that the peak-to-peak amplitude is 8X2 = 16 volts. These values agree with your generator settings. Your multimeter reading is probably not valid because most multimeters cannot measure frequencies that high. I can't be certain since you didn't identify model of your multimeter.

For the second picture, your oscillscope settings are 1 volt per division and 1 microsecond per division.  Your waveform occupies 5 vertical divisions and 3.3 horizontal divisions.  Thus it is 5X1 = 5 volts peak-to-peak and 3.3X1 =3.3 microsecond period.  Thus the frequency is the reciprocal of 3.3 microseconds or 300 kHz.  Again, these values agree with your generator. Your multimeter reading is close to the average value of your waveform (5/2 volts) but again, this frequency is probably too high for it.

Comment: Thanks for the help. The multimeter I was using should have been sufficient to take those readings. Is there some kind of online simulator (maybe free?) I can play with where I can use a function generator and hook up a multimeter? I think I've seen software like that. Anyway, if I did take the correct readings somehow (maybe you know what those should be) how would I go about confirming my reading? Thanks again.